# Include jQuery for other external library in create-react-app

Tags: jquery, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a custom library that is written in coffeescript and only depends on jQuery ($) being available.

I'm trying to include this library in an app built from facebook/create-react-app.

I'm able to import jQuery and the custom library like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
import CustomLib from 'custom-lib'

class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log($)
```

If I comment out the import CustomLib, I can see that $ is available in the constructor of MyClass, however the code as is results in ReferenceError: $ is not defined for CustomLib

Comment: Your `custom-lib` needs to import jQuery as $, I assume.

Comment: importing something into a module doesn't add it to other module's namespaces like two script tags next to each other would

Comment: I found that if I add `import $ from 'jquery'` to the top of the custom-lib dist file, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'", however if I use instead `var $ = require('jquery')` it appears to work. Not sure if there's a better approach.

Comment: Problem is I have another project that just includes the custom-lib dist file as a `<script src="dist.js"></script>`. In that case require is undefined. I'm considering passing in $ as an optional parameter to the custom-lib constructor